# Which one of the following is the proper way to return HTML via RenderActioN?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I have a small html table (Calendar) that I need to return to a page. At the parent page level, I use

@{Html.RenderAction("Calendar", "GlobalShared");}

Now, the question is I tried the following 4 ways to return the html and they all work

## 1. String

```
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public String Calendar()
        { 
               return GetCalendarHTML()
        }
```

## 2. MvcHtmlString

```
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public MvcHtmlString Calendar()
        { 
               return  MvcHtmlString.Create(GetCalendarHTML());
        }
```

## 3. ContentResult

```
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Calendar()
        { 
               return  Content(GetCalendarHTML());
        }
```

## 4. PartialViewResult

```
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult Calendar()
        { 
               return  PartialView("_Calendar", GetCalendarHTML());
        }

        _Calendar.cshtml

        @model String
        @{
           Layout = null;
         }

         @Html.Raw(Model)
```

Which way is the correct way (or better way) to return html and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PartialViewResult is what you are looking for as it is used for breaking down components of a page and making smaller sections which is what is was designed for. From my experience that is also what I have seen used a lot.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269(v=vs.98).aspx

"Renders a partial view, which defines a section of a view that can be rendered inside another view"

Comment: Tony, thanks for the reply. The thing is, the partial-view doesn't do anything other than output the raw html @Html.Raw, so then isn't that a bit of an overkill for this case? But I do understand that it's probably the proper way to do it.

Comment: How complicated is your calendar?